# Creating MVC application with dynamic views

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a requirement in our project where we have around 20-25 similar kind of screens and the development needs to be done using MVC 4 Entity Framework.
So, I was looking for a solution on creating a single dynamic view. 
So, Please suggest me and provide any useful links/sample applications if available.

Thanks in Advance,
Anand

Comment: So you want a specific part of a webpage to be the same in many other pages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial views for this purpose.
http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/2IKW160912-Partial-View-in-Asp.net-MVC3-Razor.html